# Retrieve Azure LogicApp's Connector metadata using C# SDK

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-app-service-envrmnt

Can I retrieve metadata of Connector of a Logic App using C# SDK ? Am getting logic app using: `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Logic.LogicManagementClient.Workflows.Get(resourceGroupName, logicAppName)`, but this just gives details of App and does not tell how to read metadata of connector.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Need to pull metadata of LogicApp. Assuming I created a Logic App against O365 Users Create action, I should be able to pull metadata of O365 create action etc.

Comment: What do you mean by metadata ? Logs ?

Comment: As said, in above comment, i need to see what all parameters does O365 Create action accepts

Comment: Sorry it is very unclear what's your asking for.. Your wants to know how to create the `API connector` for O365 using ARM Template ?

Comment: Let me be more clear. I have created Logic App, which says, when a HTTP POST request is received(Trigger), it should create a O365 User(Action). Now from C# SDK, I want to pull what parameters will this Action require and type of those, which basically means metadata.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for [**ListOperations**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/listoperations/listoperations) which will have the metadata

```
 url = self.list_operations.metadata['url']
```

**[SAMPLE REPOSITORY](https://github.com/capitao-red-beard/tender-manager/blob/4e911ef31b2ec4fc1cfe9ccecdb041fb7725ac1f/env/Lib/site-packages/azure/mgmt/logic/logic_management_client.py)**

Comment: Am looking for metadata on the Connector(s); not the Logic App itself. For instance, I need to retrieve all operations supported by "Azure AD" Connector. And the next level would be, to retrieve metadata supported by an action on the AzureAD connector.